# How to react on session timeout in fiori apps?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i have developed a sapui5 freestyle app, running in an sap fiori launchpad. This app extends a third party solution with a fiori frontend. All is working good so far. But this third party solution uses its own locking table for its objects and i have no possibilities to change this. So when my apps is starting, it reads the data by using an odata request (the odata services are also "my" code). This odata implementation is then adding an locking entry to the third party solution. When the user "normally" ends its work on that document using save, delete or cancel, my odata implementation of the save, delete, cancel methods also deletes the lock entry in the third party solution. Even the closing of the browser or the app is handled by attaching to special browser-events, so the locks are released in that case by calling an odata method for releasing the locks.

But what if the user starts the app (which triggers the lock) and then does nothing any more. The user is running into a session timeout. And the lock-entry for document he/she was working on is still existing.

What i need is a way to react on such a session timeout with my code which then releases the lock. Maybee an event which is triggered, or maybee there is a smart idea to dealing with such session-timeouts in the backend.

Any ideas are welcome.

kind regards
Matthias